# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character In my console?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have some problem. When I try call PHP page for some data with some requesting parameters by AJAX async call , I have error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

```
var jsonData = $.ajax({
                url: "test_getTrendsData.php",
                data: { "year" : year,"level1" : year,"filter" : getfilteredValue, "user" : user},
                dataType: "json",
                async: true
            }).responseText;
```

if I change the value of async parameter to false code running well. why this is so. I want the response text Asynchronously .......... Any help appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: please post your response.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the response you're getting back from `test_getTrendsData.php` isn't being parsed. This is most likely because it isn't valid JSON.

Comment: I check my JSON its valid JSON string